# swapping without using 3rd(temporary variable) is giving diff answer in this program can someone tell me why?

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures, quicksort, swap

when the swapping part is done with the help of 3rd variable(temporary variable) it works fine but when it is done without using temp variable(like a=a+b; b=a-b; a=a-b;)the output changes

this quick_sort program works fine but output is changing when method of swapping changes

```
#include<stdio.h>
void swap(int *a,int *b){/*
*a=*a+*b;
  *b=*a-*b;
  *a=*a-*b;*/
 int t=*a;
  *a=*b;
  *b=t;
}
int sort(int a[],int st,int piv){
int i=st-1,j,t;
for(j=st;j<=piv-1;j++){
if(a[j]<=a[piv]){
        i++;
   swap(&a[j],&a[i]);

  
}}
swap(&a[i+1],&a[piv]);
return i+1;

}
void quick(int a[],int st,int en){
if(st<en){
    int x=sort(a,st,en);
    quick(a,st,x-1);
    quick(a,x+1,st);
}
}
void main(){
int a[]={11,1,23,22,10,18,0,13},i;
quick(a,0,7);
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
printf("%d ",a[i]);

}
```

Comment: 1 tip for finding where everything goes wrong, is using a debugger (`gdb` is a popular c debugger). I ran your code in `gdb` and set a breakpoint on the function `swap`. On the first break, I'm able to see `Breakpoint 1, swap (a=0x7ffffffedf10, b=0x7ffffffedf10) at test.c:8` (notice the pointers `a`and `b` pointing to the same memory address, which holds the value 11). Stepping through the function shows how the value is reduced to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at your alternative version of swap!

```
void swap(int *a,int *b){
    *a=*a+*b;
    *b=*a-*b;
    *a=*a-*b;
}
```

Suppose `a=x,b=y`, then we get: `a=x+y`, followed by `b=x+y-y=x` and `a=x+y-x=y`. Those can prove that your code for swapping makes sense. But where's the catch? Your reasoning implies that `int* a` is independent of `int* b`. If you try calling `swap(&a[0],&a[0])` while your expected behaviour is for `a[0]` to remain unchanged this doesn't happen due to `a` and `b` pointing to the exact same memory location.

Here's a correct version of it:

```
void swap(int *a,int *b){
  if(a==b) return;
  *a=*a+*b;
  *b=*a-*b;
  *a=*a-*b;
}
```

Edit: while this method will work for most cases, it can fail due to overflow of `a+b`. Do not use it in actual code, but feel free to keep it in order to understand the reason for `if(a==b) return;`.

Comment: Unfortunately integer overflow/underflow is undefined behaviour  so not guaranteed to wrap around. This method only works if integer overflow/underflow wraps around. This code is technically undefined behaviour. You should really stick to the extra variable which shows clearly the intention instead of some cryptic method that might not even be faster.

Comment: @koder Thanks. You're right on that, I totally overlooked it myself in an effort to help the OP. I will edit my post :-)

Comment: Using xor instead of add and subtract avoids the overflow issue.